# Theoretical physics stack exchange site

Tags: discussion

This isn't really a question as such, but rather an add for another stackexchange proposal which is likely of interest to at least a few of the users here. I know this is off topic, even for meta, so I'll understand if this gets closed/deleted. CSTheory and MathOverflow have been gracious enough to allow such posts, but of course I understand that every community is different, and this may not be acceptable here.

At the moment, there is a [Theoretical Physics proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23848/theoretical-physics?referrer=6MFJJ0ze0OFN-CahX8P22A2) on Area 51, which now at 86% commitment. There are already enough low rep users, but in order to progress to beta we still need more users with over 200 rep. Although there is currently a Physics.SE it is more on the level of Math.SE than MathOverflow, and so the current proposal is for a physics site made in the image of MathOverflow/CSTheory.SE which would be explicitly research level only.

My understanding is that there are a fair number of users on this site with physics backgrounds, who may be interested in the new proposal.

In any case, if this proposal sounds of interest to you, I hope you'll consider committing so that we can progress to beta soon and make the site a reality.